# angular2 share a http service layer

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I need to make a service that can be shared between the different angular2 applications. This service will access the rest api and wrap its data so that angular application could use it. If I use angular2 http service, then I need to have the whole angular2 as a dependency for the service.

Currently I want to have the service layer as a separated npm package, so that I could reuse it between the multiple projects.

Is there a better way to achieve reusability and not install the whole angular2 library to the service package?

Comment: So the service  has `angular` npm dependency which is shared with parent package (project). What is the problem with that? Obviously, the service shouldn't be compiled to dist to be able to use the same `angular` as the project. Since the service isn't intended to be used in non-Angular environment, it should be as simple as that.

Comment: @estus the service is another package. So I want to be able to only use http, not the whole angular2 if its possible. Of course I can install the whole ng2 and as project is ng2 as well it will only be installed once.

Comment: But the service is hosted by the app, right? Then injected `Http` will come from app's injector. Service package doesn't even have to have npm `angular` dependency (even if it has, `import ... from 'angular2/http'` in service package will likely resolve to the same `angular2/http` as in project package, that's how npm packages work). The question is vague in its current state and lacks the actual code, but it looks like there's no problem here at all.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to use Angulars Http. You can build your own class that calls to [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or uses [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) directly or any other library that does AJAX requests.
- Angular is going to move Http to it's own package (out of the Angular2 main repo) https://github.com/angular/http (work in progress)
- You can create interfaces in your HTTP service layer that match the public API of the [Http](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts#L94) class and then pass a `Http` instance into the service when you bootstrap your Angular application.

```ts
interface MyHttp {
  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
  ...
}

let myHttpService = new MyHttpService();

bootstrap(AppComponent1, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(MyHttpService, {
        deps: [Http], 
        useFactory: (http) => {
          if(!myHttpService.http) {
            myService.http = http;
          }
          return myService;
        })
    })]
);
```

then in your components and services use it like

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private _myHttp: MyHttpService) {
    this._myHttp.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Hint: If you also want to inject your `MyHttpService` as a replacement of `Http` (to components and services out of your control that request `Http` use your `MyHttpService`) the provider would need to look differently.

Comment: According to the angular2 http repo its status is inactive. I understand, that  you can use your own service. But angular2 has an infrastructure of mocking and testing it all together. And angular2 is mostly build with angular2 services, like http. So using your own way with angular2 is strange as its a framework that assumes you are doing it the angular way. What am I missing?